# Javafx: Count the number of selected rows in a TableView using bind property

Tags: javafx

I want to disable a button when the number of selected rows in a tableview is different from 1 using bind property. Is possible? Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

Use `Bindings.size` on the `selectedIndices` list of the selection model:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices())
                                      .isNotEqualTo(1));
```